# Bypass DNS rebinding for localhost

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, localhost, websocket

I am encountering more and more issues with an app I created that binds to 127.0.0.1 on an obscure port. I have a domain name - due to needing an SSL cert - that resolves to 127.0.0.1.

I have this because my browser-based solution connects to the app on the local machine over a secure web socket, for example, I use wss://mydomain.com to connect.

For most people, this works just fine.

But more people are not connecting. I've come to learn DNS rebinding protections are likely at work. A solution for most people I've found is updating their local DNS to 8.8.8.8. If they do this it works. However, the out-of-the-box experience is being hindered.

Is there any reliable way to bypass DNS rebinding or set my app up in a way that doesn't have the issue?

I heard that using an obscure 127, like 127.211.134.233, could work.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you can never prevent this because web browsers also seem to implement those protections, and you can't change the web browser of a client. And if you do bypass those protections you will likely create a security threat. Isn't there a way, maybe with a reverse proxy to do it properly https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Comment: Would using 0.0.0.0 have the same issue?

Comment: Using 0.0.0.0 means all network interfaces. Don't your app has a library to properly setup a network connection? I can't imagine that in this day and age or it must be very legacy